# Lagrange Multiplier- Open Rectangular Box

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

A rectangular container is open at the top and must have a volume of 10 m<sup>3</sup>.
The material for the sides costs C dollars per m<sup>2</sup>, while the material for the bottom costs 2C dollars per m<sup>2</sup>. Find the optimal dimensions using Lagrange multipliers so as to minimize total cost of the container and what are the units for λ?

I am having trouble approaching the problem, only knowing that we start off with V= Lwh = 10 for the volume of the box. While cost = 2(wl) + 1(2wh + 2lh).

Answer (score 1):

Your constraint is on the volume, as you said
$$
g(l,w,h)=lwh=10
$$
And you are seeking to minimize the function $f(l,w,h)=2c(wl)+c(2wh+2lh)$.

So your set up is then 
$$
\nabla f=\lambda\nabla G\\
\Rightarrow 2cw+2ch=\lambda wh\\
2cl+2ch=\lambda lh\\
2cw+2cl=\lambda wl
$$
Where your answer will be in terms of $c$.